creating an azure tenant user: graph api vs @azure npm modules
I'd like to programatically create a tenant user (using registered application creds).
I can do this by hitting https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
(as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users ).
This works.  I've done it.  Great.
I'm assuming I can use "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client" to do the same thing.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client
Is there an "@azure" npm module that can do the same thing?  Like this one:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-resources
I've been calling these "@azure" modules by the name "sdk modules."  I don't know if that's the terminology of if there's a better one.
From what I can tell, there is no "@azure" module to do this.  If that's so, I don't really understand which capabilities exist in graph API and which exist in "@azure" modules and which are in both.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

The Azure (@azure) node module primarily allows developers to interact with, and manage a range of Azure resources. At the time of writing, it doesn't include an SDK for Azure AD management, however. It does provide a wrapper for authentication though, as you've probably already discovered.
If you want to avoid constructing custom HTTP requests to Graph API, you could use the microsoft-graph-client SDK from the @microsoft module. This has all the functionality for Azure AD management.
Example:
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const { ClientCredentialAuthProvider } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

async function createAzureADUser() {
    try {
        // Initialize the Graph client
        const authProvider = new ClientCredentialAuthProvider(
            process.env.CLIENT_ID,  // Your Azure AD application client ID
            process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,  // Your Azure AD application client secret
        );
        const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});

        // Create a new user
        const newUser = {
            accountEnabled: true,
            displayName: 'John Doe',
            mailNickname: 'johndoe',
            userPrincipalName: 'johndoe@example.com',
            passwordProfile: {
                forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: true,
                password: 'P@ssw0rd!'
            }
        };

        const user = await client.api('/users')
            .post(newUser);

        console.log('User created:', user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating user:', error);
    }
}

// Usage example
createAzureADUser();

